# Tactical Domino Placement Game

Tags: game, game-theory, dominoes

> Alice and Bob take turns to place regular dominoes into a $7\times8$ board. The first player who cannot go loses.

**Is there a winning strategy for either player?**

Note that in this version the pips on the domino don't count for anything - it's just about placing the dominoes into the board.

Comment: Isn’t this just https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2534/coins-on-a-table ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The player with the winning strategy is

> Alice

Strategy

> First she places a domino in the middle as follows: [image]
>  After that, whenever Bob places a domino she places hers in the position which is a $180^o$ rotation of the board from where Bob placed his. Given the symmetry she has set up, she will always be able to place a domino as long as he can.

Comment: That's pretty neat! I'd almost worked through all the possibilities of a non-symmetric game, which could be played if the board was initially set-up in a non-symmetric style, say for example randomly place 5 dominoes before the game starts. But that's a different question...

Comment: Without that added wrinkle, this question devolves to a dup of [coins on a table](/q/2534) ...